# gnuplot - 2d plots with user defined thickness

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of `x, y, t` in a text file `sect.txt`. First line represents `x1, y1 , t1` and second is `x2, y2, t1`... the 4th line(3rd line is blank) is `x3, y3, t2`, followed by `x4, y4, t3`. I want to plot a line which has coordinates `x1, y1` and `x2, y2`, with thickness `t1`. Similary next line has coords `x3, y3` and `x4, y4` with thickness `t2` and so on, for n times. With the code below, I am able to plot the 2d lines in gnuplot, but unable to incorporate thickness. Could anyone make any suggestions?

```
   0.0000000000000000        5.0000000000000000   5  
   1084.0000000000000        5.0000000000000000   5 

   542.00000000000000        10.000000000000000   1  
   542.00000000000000        981.00000000000000   1  

   0.0000000000000000        990.50000000000000   2     
   1084.0000000000000        990.50000000000000   2  

   392.00000000000000        1017.5000000000000   4.5  
   692.00000000000000        1017.5000000000000   4.5  

   392.00000000000000        1682.5000000000000   3  
   692.00000000000000        1682.5000000000000   3  

   542.00000000000000        1035.0000000000000    2 
   542.00000000000000        1665.0000000000000    2
```

code

```
 set xlabel "X Axis (Major) "
 set ylabel"Y Axis (Minor) "
 coord="sect.txt"
 set timestamp
 set autoscale keepfix
 set view equal xy 
 plot coord using 1:2 with linespoints
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, `lw` does not support the `variable` keyword as does line color `lc`. However, one could do this with a small "trick". The idea is to first determine the number of lines in the input file and then do first an auxiliary plot (per line via the `every` keyword) which loads the line widths into an array. This array is in turn used in the "real" plot:

```
fName = 'test.dat'

stat fName nooutput

#number of lines
M = int(STATS_records/2)

array lineWidths[M]

plot \
  for [i=0:M-1] fName every :::i::i u 1:(lineWidths[i+1]=$3,1/0) t '', \
  for [i=0:M-1] fName every :::i::i u 1:2 w l lw lineWidths[i+1] t sprintf("line %d", i+1)
```

For your input, this yields:
[image]

Comment: hi, i wish to represent the lines with their thicknesses. i dont mind if the color is same. just that each line appears like a rectangle with its L x B being length of line and thickness respectively